# Download file from Android shell

Tags: adb, shell, downloading, command-line

I am making a shell script for Android to run on ADB, however, the script should download a file. Commands like `wget` and `curl` aren't available in `/system/bin`. Here are a few possibble solutions that I thought of, each with its cons:

1. Rooting and installing BusyBox (my target systems are rootless)
2. Downloading file in computer using `wget` or `curl` then transferring the file to Android with `adb push` (the script should be ran on Android, not the computer connected to it)
3. Downloading `wget` or `curl` in Android (how can I download a binary without them in first place???)
4. Termux (nope, my script sets some settings in Android which Termux can't)

Is it even possile? If yes, how?

Comment: Why don't you just include an HTTP library in your command-line program and download the file yourself? You are developing a command-line program not a shell script.

Comment: I am developing a shell script. I will make edits to clarify

Comment: Put your `busybox` or `wget` or `curl` binary in `/data/local/tmp/` and execute from there. Simple.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

1. Install Termux, which supports curl.
2. Use your option number 2. `adb push` simply copies the file (unlike `adb install`, which looks for an apk file and tries to install it on the device).

Since you say that you are writing a shell script, you will have to install an Android terminal and (presumably) a Linux environment anyway.

You say "my script sets some settings in Android which Termux can't." If you need root access for an app, you may get what you need using [Magisk.](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/blob/master/README.MD)